# WPF XAML - Binding Array with variable index

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to do a databinding with an array :

```
<Button x:Name="ButtonMap" Content="{Binding Tag[0], RelativeSource={RelativeSource  AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}">
```

It works.

But, my button is in ItemsControl and I succeeded to get index of the current item like that :

```
{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
            StringFormat={}Index is {0}}
```

Now, I would use this index to get the nth element of my array. Like that :

```
<Button x:Name="ButtonMap" Content="{Binding Tag[index], RelativeSource={RelativeSource  AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}">
```

I tried to use a StaticResource but the Binding didn't work.

Can you help me please ?

EDIT : 
XAML File :

```
`<UserControl x:Class="INSAWorldWPF.Views.GameView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:INSAWorldWPF"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:INSAWorldWPF.ViewModels"
         xmlns:custom1="clr-namespace:INSAWorld;assembly=INSAWorld"
         xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Views/Resources/background2.jpg"/>
</UserControl.Background>

<!--<Button Height="50" Margin="0,30" Command="{Binding TestCommand, Mode=OneWay}" Content="Demo Map"/>-->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0,0,0">
            <StackPanel.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray" Opacity=".3"/>
            </StackPanel.Background>
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageRace}" Width="200" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,20" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PseudoCurrentPlayer}" FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/Views/Resources/#Ringbearer Medium" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="60"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/Views/Resources/#Cosmic Love" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="40" Text="LifePoint : "/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/Views/Resources/#Cosmic Love" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="40" Text="{Binding LifePoint}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/Views/Resources/#Cosmic Love" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="40" Text="MovePoint : "/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/Views/Resources/#Cosmic Love" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="40" Text="{Binding MovePoint}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0">
            <StackPanel.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray" Opacity=".3"/>
            </StackPanel.Background>

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListTile}" AlternationCount="150" Tag="{Binding UnitByTile}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate.Resources>
                        <custom:TypeOfConverter x:Key="typeOfConverter" />
                        <System:Double x:Key="theMargin">0</System:Double>
                    </DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <Button x:Name="ButtonMap" Content="{Binding Path=Tag[?????????], RelativeSource={RelativeSource  AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}">

                        <Button.Resources>

                        </Button.Resources>
                        <Button.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Button">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            </Border>
                                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                                                </Trigger>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                                                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.7" />
                                                </Trigger>
                                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource typeOfConverter} }" Value="Desert">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource typeOfConverter} }" Value="Swamp">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkKhaki" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource typeOfConverter} }" Value="Volcano">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource typeOfConverter} }" Value="Plain">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="ForestGreen" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Style>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding SizeMap}" Rows="{Binding SizeMap}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="600"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

`

Comment: Is the Tag array the same collection that your ItemsControl is bound to? Can you post the XAML for the itemscontrol?

Comment: I edited my question with the XAML

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the usage of a `MultiValueConverter`. Assuming that `Tag[]` is of type `string[]` you could use the following:

```
public class ArrayItemSelector : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //Check given arguments first
        if(!(values.Length > 1) || !(values[0] is string[]) || !(values[1] is int))
            throw new ArgumentException("given values not correct");

        return ((string[]) values[0])[(int) values[1]];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

usage:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <namespace:ArrayItemSelector x:Key="ArrayItemSelector" />
</Grid.Resources>
<!-- .................. -->
<Button x:Name="ButtonMap">
    <Button.Content>
         <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ArrayItemSelector}">
             <Binding Path="Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource  AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}" />
             <Binding Path="(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
         </MultiBinding>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

A simple `ValueConverter` won't work, because the `ConverterParameter` needs to be static. The index you'd like to use need to be bound.

Hope this works for you

Comment: Just a comment based on the current documentation at Microsoft Learn: Returning null from the ConvertBack method is preferred to indicate it's an ambiguous or impossible conversion. If using nullability context, be sure to make the return type and parameters nullable, so static analysis is correct.